# Haskell Existential Types

Tags: haskell, existential-type

I'm trying to wrap my brain around Haskell's existential types, and my first example is a heterogeneous list of things that can be shown:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
data Showable = forall a. Show a => Showable a

showableList :: [Showable]
showableList = [Showable "frodo", Showable 1]
```

Now it seems to me that the next thing I would want to do is make Showable an instance of Show so that, for example, my showableList could be displayed in the repl:

```
instance Show Showable where
  show a = ...
```

The problem I am having is that what I really want to do here is call the *a*'s underlying *show* implementation. But I'm having trouble referring to it:

```
instance Show Showable where
  show a = show a
```

picks out *Showable*'s show method on the RHS which runs in circles. I tried auto-deriving Show, but that doesn't work:

```
data Showable = forall a. Show a => Showable a
  deriving Show
```

gives me:

```
Can't make a derived instance of `Show Showable':
  Constructor `Showable' does not have a Haskell-98 type
  Possible fix: use a standalone deriving declaration instead
In the data type declaration for `Showable'
```

I'm looking for someway to call the underlying Show::show implementation so that *Showable* does not have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: The fanciness and complexity of `data Showable = forall a . Show a => Showable a` is leading you to forget that `Showable` (on the right hand side) is just another constructor like `Just` or `Left`. It's not different from a case where you'd written `data Showable a = Showable a` -- you wouldn't try to write `instance Show a => Show (Showable a) where show x = ...?...`; rather you'd instance with `... where show (Showable x) = show x` or maybe `where show (Showable x) = "Showable  " ++ show x`.  You want to get your hands on the thing that is wrapped inside `Showable` as Logan notes.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
instance Show Showable where
   show (Showable a) = show a
```

`show a = show a` doesn't work as you realized because it recurses infinitely. If we try this without existential types we can see the same problem and solution

```
data D = D Int
instance Show D where show a = show a -- obviously not going to work

instance Show D where show (D a) = "D " ++ (show a) -- we have to pull out the underlying value to work with it
```

Comment: @Ara Vartanian I added a little elaboration. Do you see now why it's not really anything to do with existential types and just a matter of defining your function correctly?

Comment: Ahh... Yes. Now I get it. I have to use pattern matching to pull apart the instance to get at the show method I want. Thank you so much.

Comment: Note that this example is a bit clearer if you use GADT syntax anyway, writing `data Showable where Showable :: Show a => a -> Showable`. That GADTs deprive you of some automatic deriving is a familiar point.